# Android a seekbar for adjusting bitmap brightness

Tags: android, image, bitmap, seekbar, brightness

I have tryed many codes, and looked at Android developers but couldn't make it work. I want the seek bar to adjust my bitmap image brightness

Answer (score 8, accepted):

check the example given at [Increase/Decrease Brightness of Image](http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/22/image-processing-brightness-over-image/)

and do as shown below on seekbar progress changes

```
 int brightness;
 SeekBar seekbarbrightness=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
 seekbarbrightness.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

         @Override
         public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         }

         @Override
         public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         }

         @Override
         public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2) {

             // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             brightness=progress;
             Bitmap bitmap=doBrightness(originalbitmap,brightness);
             imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
         }
        });
```

Comment: ty , but it gives me this error in the public voids "The method onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar) of type new OnSeekBarChangeListener(){} must override a superclass method" and i can fix it by removing the "@override" ..

Comment: The method onProgressChanged(SeekBar, int, boolean) of type new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){} must override a superclass method

Comment: @Khan i tried your solution but when i increase the seekbar the process performes very slowly as if the app gets hanged.so i wanted to ask you how to speedup the seekbar's performance.if you get any solution for it i will be thankful.

Answer (score 1):

check the example given at Increase/Decrease Brightness of Image

```
     int brightness;
 SeekBar seekBarBrightness=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
 seekBarBrightness.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

     @Override
     public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {


     }

     @Override
     public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {


     }

     @Override
     public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2) {

       Bitmap newBitMap  =   doBrightness(bitMap,progress);

       imageView.setImageBitmap(newBitMap);

     }
    });




    public static Bitmap doBrightness(Bitmap src, int value)
    {
        // image size
        int width = src.getWidth();
        int height = src.getHeight();
        // create output bitmap
        Bitmap bmOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, src.getConfig());
        // color information
        int A, R, G, B;
        int pixel;

        // scan through all pixels
        for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
                    {
                        // get pixel color
                        pixel = src.getPixel(x, y);
                        A = Color.alpha(pixel);
                        R = Color.red(pixel);
                        G = Color.green(pixel);
                        B = Color.blue(pixel);

                        // increase/decrease each channel
                        R += value;
                        if (R > 255)
                            {
                                R = 255;
                            } else if (R < 0)
                            {
                                R = 0;
                            }

                        G += value;
                        if (G > 255)
                            {
                                G = 255;
                            } else if (G < 0)
                            {
                                G = 0;
                            }

                        B += value;
                        if (B > 255)
                            {
                                B = 255;
                            } else if (B < 0)
                            {
                                B = 0;
                            }

                        // apply new pixel color to output bitmap
                        bmOut.setPixel(x, y, Color.argb(A, R, G, B));
                    }
            }

        // return final image
        return bmOut;
    }
```

Comment: this algotithm is not optimized at all , with the new phones a pic can have more than 10 mb and you won t see in real time the changes

Comment: It works fine. but it takes too long to perform changes.

Answer (score 1):

Use this example

```
SeekBar sb_value = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sb_value);
        final ImageView im_brightness = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.im_brightness);
        sb_value.setProgress(125);
        sb_value.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

                im_brightness.setColorFilter(setBrightness(progress));

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
```

setBrightness method:

```
public static PorterDuffColorFilter setBrightness(int progress) {
        if (progress >=    100)
        {
            int value = (int) (progress-100) * 255 / 100;

            return new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.argb(value, 255, 255, 255), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER);

        }
        else
        {
            int value = (int) (100-progress) * 255 / 100;
            return new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.argb(value, 0, 0, 0), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Ragu Ram with smooth seek bar performance.
For Kotlin

```
    val seekBarBrightness : SeekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekBarBrightness)

    seekBarBrightness.max = 255
    seekBarBrightness.min = -255

    seekBarBrightness.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
        override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar, progress: Int,
                                       fromUser: Boolean) {
            imageView.colorFilter = setBrightness(progress)
        }

        override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar) {
        }

        override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar) {
        }
    })
```

Set Brightness

```
fun setBrightness(progress : Int): PorterDuffColorFilter {
    return if (progress >= 0) {
        PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.argb(progress, 255, 255, 255), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER)
    } else {
        val value = 255 - progress
        PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.argb(value, 0, 0, 0), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP)
    }
}
```