# How can I modify parts of Image View?

Tags: android, android-studio, imageview

I have an imageview in my project and i want to allow the users to change the exposure, brightness, contrast and sharpness using seekbar and also blur parts of image

How can I implement that without any use of library?

Comment: Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11663293/12151975

Answer (score 1):

You need to do some pixel based operation.

1. Get pixel values (RGBA based)
2. Do some modification with that
3. Assemble them into an bitmap.
4. Show the bitmap into the ImageView.

There are many proven algorithms to do that pixel operations.